# Kotlin Elvis Statement with Live Data

Tags: android, kotlin

We have a common flow pattern in our code base in Android Java, but I am trying to learn Kotlin so I want to try and get the best statement to be used throughout the code. The follow pattern is usually that a user hits a button gets a dialog and we have to build up the data. The line below is what I want to try to make more efficient.

```
 viewModel.getLiveData().value
                        ?.let {  viewModel.setTarget(viewModel.getLiveData().value!!.copy(targetNumber = result)) }
                        ?: viewModel.setTarget(Target(result, null))
```

Here is my basic fragment

```
class DemoFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_demo_layout) {
private val viewModel: DemoViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    btn_toast.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    btn_toast.setOnLongClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hello long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        true
    }

    viewModel.getLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { target -> updateUI(target) }

    btnTargetNumber.setOnClickListener {
        val dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_text_entry, null)

        AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Enter Target Number")
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                run {
                    val result =
                        dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.targetNumberInput).editableText.toString()
                    viewModel.getLiveData().value
                        ?.let {  viewModel.setTarget(viewModel.getLiveData().value!!.copy(targetNumber = result)) }
                        ?: viewModel.setTarget(Target(result, null))
                }

            }.show()
    }
}

private fun updateUI(target: Target?) {
    btnTargetNumber.text = target?.targetNumber
}
```

}

Here is the simple view model

```
class DemoViewModel(private val handle : SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
 private val targetData : MutableLiveData<Target> = MutableLiveData()

fun setTarget (target: Target){
    targetData.value = target
}

fun  getLiveData() : LiveData<Target>
{
    return targetData
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be simplified to a single call to `setTarget` and inside the call `?:` will do this with simplification.

```
viewModel.setTarget(viewModel.getLiveData().value?.copy(targetNumber = result)?:Target(result, null))
```

In above
viewModel.getLiveData().value?.copy(targetNumber = result) this will either execute if `value`not null else the part after `?:` i.e. `Target(result, null)`. So you can acheive the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `it` inside `let` to get the non-null value instead of writing whole statement again and set the `target` outside let without duplicating statement

```
viewModel.setTarget(viewModel.getLiveData().value?.let { it.copy(targetNumber = result) }?: Target(result, null))
```